# Certmanger with AWS PCA on other clouds

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I am looking for mtls on both aks and gke clusters with certmanager and I am also leveraging AWS private CA with it.
I am stuck with an error of certificate generation. I created secret with aws access and secret keys. Post that I gave the clusterissuer and certificate request. However I see an error "Issuer not ready".

```
kubectl get certificate
NAME            READY   SECRET       AGE
rsa-cert-4096   False   pca-secret   43m
```

I checked the logs of certmanager but I dont see much information apart from below:

```
"cert-manager/certificates-trigger: Certificate must be re-issued" key="default/rsa-cert-4096" reason="MissingData" message="Issuing certificate as Secret does not contain a private key"
```